# Merge 3 different json arrays in one object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have three different arrays which I want to merge them into a single object.

```
array 1 : [{"Id":1,"Number":"1234","Category":"Chocalte", "Status": "Error"}]

heatingissues: [{"myId":3,"Id":"5801"}]

problemissue: [{"myId":1,"Id":2,"Name":"Desktop"}]
```

I want result to be like this:

```
{
    "Id": 3,
    "Number": "1190042293",
    "Category": "Chocalte",
    "heatingissues": [
        {
            "myId": 3,
            "id": "5801"
        }
    ],
    "problemissue": [
        {
            "myId": 1,
            "name": "Desktop"
        }
    ]
}
```

After deserializing all the arrays individually (respectively to the `results` and `problemissueresults` variables) I try:

```
  var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{
            results,
            heatingissues= problemissueresults,
            problemissue= problemissueresults

            });
```

Which generates the following output:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Number": "1190042293",
            "category": "Chocalte"
        }
    ],
    "heatingissues": [
        {
            "myId": 3,
            "id": "5801"
        }
    ],
    "problemissue": [
        {
            "myId": 1,
            "name": "Desktop"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I avoid these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to declare explicitly the properties of the object you are serializing to match the format you want.

In words of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for C# Anonymous Types:

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being used to initialize them

So your `result` was being serialized as an array with a json key of the same name.

Try this:

```
var obj =
  new
  {
    id = results[0].id,
    number = results[0].number,
    category = results[0].category,
    heatingissues= problemissueresults,
    problemissue= problemissueresults
  };
var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: What to do in case first array was not an array but an object ??

Comment: You access the object's properties directly. `id = results.id`(assuming the object has an `id` property)

Comment: :This will not be a cleaner way of doing things are i am having 50 properties

Comment: You need to define the structure of the json you want to generate with all of its respective keys. If you think that an anonymous type object with too many properties might not be clean enough, then you could create a class whose properties match the keys of your json. Then you could pass the objects containing the data to the class's constructor, and initialize the properties inside the constructor. Finally, you could use that constructor to create a new object and pass it to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: I am able to achieve it as follows:JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(results);
                jo.Add("heatingissues", heatingissuesresults);
                jo.Add("problemissue", problemissueresults); and passed it to JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Comment: That's another valid way, but that would include the `Status` key in your json, which originally you didn't want

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft json library support merging operation.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm